# Mule 4 : XML Module : How to retrieve values from a XML message having fields with namespaces using XPATH?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have a sample xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body>
  <m:GetPriceResponse xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
    <m:Price>1.90</m:Price>
  </m:GetPriceResponse>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Using Mule 4 XMl module, I want to retrieve the value of "Price".

I am trying the below code :

```
#[XmlModule::xpath('//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/m:GetPriceResponse/m:Price', payload, {})]
```

However its not working. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: I'm terribly curious about why not just using plain DataWeave for that. Is as simple as '#[output application/java --- payload.Envelope.Body.GetPriceResponse.Price]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
#[output application/java ---  XmlModule::xpath('//*:Price/text()', payload.^raw, {})[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to use plain DataWeave code in Mule 4. Please find below code.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.Envelope.Body.GetPriceResponse.Price
```

Comment: Getting an error : Trying to output non-whitespace characters outside main element tree (in prolog or epilog), while writing Xml at ." evaluating expression: "payload.Envelope.Body.GetPriceResponse.Price".

Comment: You need to use application/java as output. Or if you are using application/XML ,you have to add root element in DataWeave like myRoot: above expression